# In C#, How to convert a date time string with timezone to DateTime?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timezone

I have a C# string variable which is defined like this :

```
string sTestDate = "17 février 2016 15:49:02 UTC+1";
```

How can i format to `DateTime` variable?

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sTestDate  [format ?], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: you must separate your string by month, day and year and then convert it to your local time with adding UTC time. in this way there is no way to directly convert it to DateTime variable

Comment: `DateTime myDate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(sTestDate, "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'UTC'z", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));`

Comment: Sorry it should be `DateTimeOffset myDate ` :)

Comment: @Soner Gönül Thank's. It's perfect.